# Image chooser webcomponents

Tags: javascript, images, html

Are there any [webcomponents](http://webcomponents.org/) out there that provide controls for choosing/previewing images on webpages. Ideally they should allow users to drag & drop images, open them via a file selection dialog and download them from URLs. Being able to do some cropping/resizing after the fact would also be a nice feature to have.